# What can I do if weight decreasing stopped after I reached half of my goal?

Tags: weight-loss, diet, bmr

When I started my diet I was at **82kg** now my weight oscillates between **74** and **75kg**. I've read that I should target **0.5-1kg** weekly weight loss. I tried out a diet with **0.75**. I've calculated that my **BMR** is 1,659 Calories/day and my diet contains food equals to 1600 Calories/day.

A friend of mine who is a dietitian said that I should not decrease my daily calorie intake below my **BMR** since it can result in an unfavorable response from my body: it can adapt to prolonged decrease in calorie intake and lower its energy needs. I am not a dietitian but I'm stuck with **75kg** while my diet in theory should result in a **0.75kg** weight loss per week. What could be the problem? Can it be the case described above? If yes what can I do?

Note that I always calculate the weight loss into my daily calorie needs so for example when I was *82kg* I was eating something around *1700* calories and now it is around *1600*.

I am doing resistance training (2 times per week) and HIIT (2-3 times a week) on different days of each week.

*Edit: My height is 168cm and my parameters did not change significantly in the past several weeks (waist/shoulder/etc size)*

Comment: How tall are you? 75kg could be a healthy weight, over or under weight depending on your height. Also, if you are working out you may be building muscle at approximately the same rate you are losing fat.

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't lower your calorie intake, maybe you should try increasing your workouts a little bit.

Personally, I find 0.5 kg/week already very taxing on my body, especially when I do it several months, as I'm doing right now. In my experience, 0.5 kg/2 weeks is much more doable, while 2 kg/month is easy. But then, I run more than 60 km per week, requiring over 4000 kcal/day. All I have to do is keep my daily intake slightly below 3600 kcal or so, in other words, eat normal, but no more.

Even so, I don't loose weight gradually. It goes in fits and starts. I expect that might be happening to you as well. Be more patient with the results and don't focus on the day-by-day development too much. It's better to see the bigger picture, by putting your weight in a year graph.